# Paperclip processor - How to use paperclip logger in my own processor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to write my own paperclip processor, but how should I log to the paperclip logger?

I tried the following, `log 'here is the processor'` doesn't put out anything. How should I do that?

```
module Paperclip
  class MyProcessor < Processor
    include Paperclip::Logger

    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @format         = options[:format]
      @current_format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    def make
      log 'here is the processor'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Paperclip logging is turned on it it's initializer?

Comment: Yes, the paperclip logging is on. I could see other default paperclip messages in my log.

Comment: Are you sure your custom processor is called? Is it currently just the above posted snippet or did you just extract the lines of importance?

Comment: Yes, if I replace log with `puts`, I could see the message in my development log.

Answer (score 2):

If, in your processor you need to log, the log method is part of the Paperclip module

```
Paperclip.log "Log something"
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/logger.rb

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to call it this way:

```
def make
  logger.log 'here is the processor'
end
```

No possibility to test it here - so cannot promise you anything. :)

Comment: What happens when you call
logger.info("[paperclip] here is the processor") 
?